# Java Inheritance: Superclass being "overriden" by Subclass function with different signature

Tags: java, oop

I am quite rusty on my Java and I'm having a hard time with the following:

```
public abstract class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {

    //enum stored elsewhere
    AnimalType type = null;

    private specificCompare(Animal a){
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Animal a){
        int comp = type.compareTo(a.type);
        if (comp > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (comp < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return specificCompare(a);
        }
    }
}

public class Mammal extends Animal {
    private mammalStuff;

    public Mammal(){
        ...
    }

    public specificCompare(Mammal m){
       //do specific comparison
    }
}
```

So, I understand *why* Mammal's specificCompare isn't being called (incorrect type) but I'm trying to figure out a clean way to make this work. I want to be able to extend Animal and have it correctly call a specific comparison when needed.

In addition to the actual answer, if anyone has suggested documentation for me to read on this I would be happy to have a link to it.

Comment: You want every class of `Animal` to define its own `specificCompare()`, right? Your current code doesn't work? What is it giving that you don't want?

Comment: override the specificCompare(Animal a) instead of redefining it. it's private in super class make it protected.

Comment: @acdcjunior: It is always returning 0 instead of calling the Mammal specificCompare.

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha: I can make it protected and override it, but then I cannot use the mammalStuff in my comparison. Do I need to cast to Mammal inside?

Comment: Overriding compareTo is almost impossible without breaking its contract, because the contract specifies that animal.compareTo(mammal) and mammal.compareTo(animal) must be compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the parent function and just cast the Animal parameter to Mammal or whatever specific subclass.

```
public class Mammal extends Animal {
    private mammalStuff;

    public Mammal(){
        ...
    }

    public int specificCompare(Animal a){
       Mammal m = (Mammal)a;
       //do specific comparison
    }
```

You're only calling specificCompare (see: Animal.compareTo) when you KNOW that both objects are the same type, so this won't fail.

Comment: Often.. it's best to check for the type before attempting a cast. Otherwise the exception thrown isn't meaningful to the person using your code. And you control program flow a little better this way.

Comment: This solution breaks the contract of compareTo.

Comment: @foolmoron: no, it won't. It will be called with whatever animal type being in the collection of animals to sort.

Comment: @JBNizet But if the animal types are different, Animal.compareTo will return before calling this function, right?

Comment: Hmm. I overlooked the first part of the compareTo method. It could work if it's guaranteed that every time the method is overridden, the type is also made different, and if all mammals have the same type (which is not obvious in the OP). My down vote is not really deserved. If you edit your answer, I'll be allowed to remove it.

Comment: You were correct in this answer. I added the type check per Chris Cooney.  I also changed the Animal specificCompare to abstract to ensure that it is overridden.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit in response to your comment**

Well, it seems to me that if you simply want to compare types, without knowing their specific classes, you can only get as accurate as `Animal`, without casting them. This is because that is the most specific common link between all animals. What you could do, is provide an abstract method in `Animal`, that has some sort of value.

```
public int returnType();
// Abstract method in Animal class.
```

And in the `Mammal` class, it might look like this:

```
public int returnType()
{
    // Purely an example.
    return Animal.MAMMAL;
}
```

By calling `returnType` on the objects that you are passed, you can learn something unique about the objects passed to you, without knowing their instance types and without ever having to cast.

Comment: My intention was to allow the comparison of types of Animals without knowledge of instance to allow additional animal types to be added later.

I would like to have Animal be able to exist such that all code that would be added with new animal types would exist within their own specificCompare.

Comment: Take a look at my new suggestion @useSticks

Comment: +1 to the last part, and -1 to the first part, which will likely break the compareTo contract.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding a method means that the signature is exactly the same. The signature consists of the name and its arguments. You `Mammal` class doesn't override `specificCompare(Animal a)` it is defining a new function.

If you want to explicit call the function in Mammal you would have to do something like `specificCompare((Mammal) a)` inside of Animal and then it would find the correct signature. This is obviously not desired though.

Just match the signatures exactly so it overrides it and then test to see if `a` is a Mammal. If it is cast it and go along with your logic. If it isn't you should probably throw a `ClassCastException`

Comment: I should also note that you cannot make specificCompare private instead make it at least protected so it can be overridden.